# Display value returned from JOIN query

Tags: 7

I am unable to display the value returned from my JOIN query, the error i get is:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_brand_value
```

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT nid, title FROM {node} AS n JOIN {field_data_field_brand} AS brand ON brand.entity_id = n.nid WHERE created > :created";

$args = array(':created' => REQUEST_TIME - 3600);

$result = db_query($sql, $args);

foreach ($result as $obj) {
  drupal_set_message("title: {$obj->title} brand: {$obj->field_brand_value}", "warning");
}
```

Comment: Your query is right, but I think name field_data_field_brand is not right, normally when you create field via Drupal it will have suffix value so it should be field_data_field_brand_value, Can you check your database for correct field table name?

Comment: Thanks @Ziftman field_data_field_brand is the name of the table, and the name of the field I'm trying to display is field_brand_value

Comment: True, I catch it, field_brand_value is not in the result, you just selecting nid and title. Btw I suggest using entity query rather than doing direct sql join.